# Implementing json file(Spine) in Cocos Creator with js

Tags: javascript

I want to select 3 type of file(atlas,PNG and JSON) from local drive, then create a Node in the Cocos Creator and run the Spine animation.

the Nodes can't add the Skeleton Data like how you drag it in the Cocos Creator editor.
I have try many way, but the JSON(Spine) is not added into the Node's Skeleton Data, and can't generate the animation.

Is there any way can solve this?

cc.Class({
extends: cc.Component,

```
properties: {
    middle:cc.Node,
    testing: cc.Node,
    testing2: cc.Node,
},

onLoad () {
    // Add click event listener to the button
    this.node.on('click', this.onSelectFile, this);
},

onSelectFile() {
    // Create and configure file input element
    const input = document.createElement('input');
    input.type = 'file';
    input.accept = '.atlas, .png, .json'; // Accept all three types of files
    input.multiple = true; // Allow selection of multiple files
        
    // Trigger click event on the file input
    input.click();

    // Listen for file selection
    input.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
        const files = event.target.files;
        if (files.length === 0) return;

        let atlasFile, pngFile, jsonFile;

        // Loop through selected files to find the corresponding types
        for (const file of files) {
            if (file.name.endsWith('.atlas')) {
                atlasFile = file;
            } else if (file.name.endsWith('.png')) {
                pngFile = file;
            } else if (file.name.endsWith('.json')) {
                jsonFile = file;
            }
        }

        // Ensure all necessary files are selected
        if (!atlasFile || !pngFile || !jsonFile) {
            cc.log('Please select an atlas file, a PNG file, and a JSON file.');
            return;
        }


        // Load atlas, PNG, and JSON files
        Promise.all([
            this.loadFileAsText(atlasFile),
            this.loadFileAsDataURL(pngFile),
            this.loadFileAsText(jsonFile)
        ]).then(([atlasText, pngDataURL, jsonData]) => {
            this.createSkeletonNode(atlasText, pngDataURL, JSON.parse(jsonData));
        }).catch(error => {
            console.error('Failed to load files:', error);
        });
    });
},

loadFileAsText(file) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (event) => resolve(event.target.result);
        reader.onerror = (error) => reject(error);
        reader.readAsText(file);
    });
},

loadFileAsDataURL(file) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (event) => resolve(event.target.result);
        reader.onerror = (error) => reject(error);
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
},

createSkeletonNode(atlasText, pngDataURL, jsonData) {
    // Load PNG texture
    cc.assetManager.loadRemote(pngDataURL, { ext: '.png' }, (err, texture) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Failed to load PNG file:', err);
            return;
        }

        // Create a new node for the PNG, and set it inactive
        const pngNode = new cc.Node();
        const pngSprite = pngNode.addComponent(cc.Sprite);
        pngSprite.spriteFrame = new cc.SpriteFrame(texture);
        pngNode.active = false;
            
        // Add the pngNode to the skeleton's skeletonData
        //jsonData.AtlasTexture = pngNode.uuid;

        // Create a new node with sp.Skeleton component
        const skeletonNode = new cc.Node();
        const skeleton = skeletonNode.addComponent(sp.Skeleton);
        skeleton.skeletonData = jsonData;
        skeleton.defaultSkin = "default";
        skeletonNode.active = true;

        cc.log(this.testing._components," 2");
        cc.log(skeletonNode._components," 4");

        // Add both nodes to the middle node
        this.middle.addChild(pngNode);
        this.middle.addChild(skeletonNode);
    });
},
```

});